# .NET Submitting HTTP request to webservice that requires nameless parameter in query string

Tags: .net, web-services, query-string, webclient

I'm creating some classes to interact with a web service (built by a 3rd party), that in (almost) all cases only accepts GET queries.

One of my classes is a WebServiceClient class, which encapsulates a System.Net.WebClient class, which I've found really useful, because it allows you to add name=value pairs via its QueryString property.  I've used this extensively.

One of the requests that the service accepts however, resembles this:

```
http://host:port/endpoint?C:/path/to/file/today.xml&Database=News&Destination=Server
```

Now, obviously, I'm used to values in the querystring being of the form name=value, but in the above example, the first parameter seems to have no name.

Is there a way to replicate this using WebClient or a different .NET class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom subclass that behaves like a WebClient but adds the required weirdness like so:
The GetWebRequest methods need to be overriden to take into account our new property NameLessParameter to build a new Uri.

```
public class SpecializedWebClient : WebClient
{
    // set if you need Namelessvalue as 
    // your first QueryParam
    public string NameLessParameter { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var u = new UriBuilder(address);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NameLessParameter))
        {
            string origQuery = String.Empty;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Query))
            {
                // strip off the first ? and add &
                origQuery = "&" + u.Query.Substring(1);
            }
            u.Query = NameLessParameter + origQuery;
        }
        return base.GetWebRequest(u.Uri);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var sc = new SpecializedWebClient();
sc.QueryString.Add("foo", "42");
sc.QueryString.Add("bar", "pi");
sc.NameLessParameter=@"c:\bofh\removeuser.sh";
string sdta = sc.DownloadString(@"http://www.example.com");
```